# Which is the fastest way to get a URL from an HTML tag (Regex, NScanner, Hppple)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, performance, hpple

I found 3 different way to get the value of the `src` attribute of an `img` tag in an HTML string.

1. With a Regex using RegexKitLite.
2. With TFHpple HTML parser
3. Using a NSSCanner to scan the HTML string.

So which way I must use to optimize performance of my iPhone app?

Comment: If you do not know you should measure it.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regexes [may not be a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: @Claszen how can I miseure it?? Wich app can I use? thanks

Comment: Independent from what you do I would say to measure the time you **(1)** Take current time on start **(2)** do what you want to measure **(3)** take current time when done **(4)** calculate the time gap.

Comment: @Josh: true (upvote). Finding an image tag maybe doesn't really count as parsing, but more as trying to find something within a text. At which RegExes do a very good job.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the fastest, but RegEx is imho the most versatile and portable method. And unless you're really doing hundreds of parses per second, you won't notice the performance hit you'll get by not using the fastest method around..

I use lots of regexes on iPhone for user input validation while the user is entering text (so a lag would certainly be seen). Never had any problems.